# Descendant selectors ignore the styles - JSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, object, jss

I want to use descendant selectors with JSS to style all descendant elements with certain styles and descendant input elements with another style, but it doesn't work.

First I thought that the problem is with syntax, but I looked at this [article](https://medium.com/the-clever-dev/jss-selectors-and-syntax-rules-e4008e07966b), and the syntax was the same that in my code.

After that, I tried to remove the classes from my descendant elements, because I thought that something wrong with inheritance and style priority, but it didn't work either.

Here is my code:
React:

```
...
<div className={addProductContainer}>
    <div className={inputsContainer}>
        <input
            onChange={onNewItemNameChange}
            value={newItem.name}
            // className={productInput}
            type="text"
        />
        <input
            onChange={onNewItemAmountChange}
            onKeyDown={keyDown}
            value={newItem.amount}
            // className={amountInput}
            type="number"
        />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit} className={submitBtn}>Add New Product</button>
    </div>
</div> 
...
```

And the JSS:

```
...
inputsContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 80,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 175, 1)',
    '& *': {
        height: 40,
        boxSizing: 'border-box'
    },
    '& input': {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        border: 'none',
        fontFamily: ['Lexend Deca', 'sans-serif'],
        width: '40%',
        padding: 5,
        borderRadius: [[5, 0, 0, 5]],
        fontSize: '1rem',
        border: 'none'
    },
    '& input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, &input::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
        '-webkit-appearance': 'none'
    }
},
// productInput: {
//     width: '40%',
//     padding: 5,
//     borderRadius: [[5, 0, 0, 5]],
//     fontSize: '1rem',
//     border: 'none'
// },
// amountInput: {
//     '-moz-appearance': 'textfield',
//     width: 70,
//     textAlign: 'center',
//     fontSize: '1.5rem',
//     border: [[1, 'solid', 'black']],
//     borderRadius: [[0, 5, 5, 0]]
// },
...
```

Here you can see that I removed the classes, and put all styles from `productInput` to the descendant. When it was in class, it was working fine, but as a descendant, it doesn't work.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you share a runnable example, where it fails?

Comment: @JosefWittmann sorry I can't share the whole working code with you :( Can you create a little working example? I will appreciate it :)

Comment: You may try to reproduce it yourself. Create a minimal example, where it fails. And if it does not fail, it'll help you debug things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `'& > *'` to set style to all descendants

Comment: Sorry, it didn't helped too.